# Python discord bots

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to create my discord bot. sadly, this does not work and I have no Idea why...

```
import discord
import os
import time
from ka import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
prefix = '.'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm ready! {0.user}".format(client))
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Croissants!"))

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
  channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
  await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
  await ctx.send("On my way!")

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

there are NO errors. But no output aswell. I try making it join my vc by writing: .join

Comment: Can you share the contents of `ka.py`? (You're probably running this on a repl)

Comment: I am yes. ka.py ist just sending requests to it every 5 min so the bot does not go offline

Comment: Are you running it in a seperate thread?

Comment: no i dont really know what that is but i dont think so
My problem is that the command events arent being called...

Comment: Lets take this to a [chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229172/discord-py-support-for-executive-meek)

Comment: cant. I need 20 reputation i only have 11

Comment: well now you have 21

Answer (score 1):

`channel` returns `None`, because `ctx.message.author` don't have `voice` attribute. Also, `Client.join_voice_channel` is deprecated since v1.0 ([read here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#migrating-1-0-voice))

Instead of that, try this:

```
import discord
import os
import time
from ka import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
prefix = '.'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm ready! {0.user}".format(client))
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Croissants!"))

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
  channel = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.author.id).voice.channel # This
  await channel.connect()
  await ctx.send("On my way!")

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: He says that there is no output, so that means that on_ready isn't even running, so the bot isn't starting up in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. that might have fixed it but my real problem is that command events, dont even get called AT ALL If you have discord would you mind talking there? we can respond faster and its easier to text

Comment: I didn't even notice that you don't loaded .env file, where is your token

Comment: the token aint the problem the bot works and already has a few simple commands working but I dont use the command event i use the on message event

Comment: @executivemeek That's strange, because in theory that should work. You can try use `@commands.command()` instead of `@client.command()` and add `client.add_command()`. If that won't work, use `on_message` event

Answer (score 0):

Do `client.add_command(join)`. You currently have the function for your command, but you haven't told the bot to recognize it as a command.

Comment: You only need to do that if you are using the `commands.command()` decorator. `client.command()` registers it just fine.

Comment: Do you mean ('join')

Comment: @executivemeek no it does not need a string because you defined it as a function before